# Connect REST API on Pi to the Cloud

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, cloud, iot

I am relatively new to programming. I have a project where I need to control things like pumps and read data from sensors. I currently have a flask webserver set up on a raspberry and can access that website only from within my local network.

My objective is to change my flask webserver to a flask REST APi. Then I want to set up my raspberry pi on a cloud/iot platform and control my pi over the cloud via the flask REST api.

Any idea on how to best do this? Ive been researching it a lot and could use some help.

Answer (score 1):

I would setup the api endpoints like you discussed. Those endpoints I assume would allow you to control the sensors and whatever other hardware is attached to the GPIO. Then as you mentioned you would expose that API to some sort of an IOT platform. AWS offers a nice solution however there are many.

Comment: awesome thank you. Like I said I am new to this type of work. Does that mean the format/style of the local flask webserver I have now on my local network will be what I see when i set up the pi to control over the cloud?

Comment: Yes sir, you should be able to test out the endpoints on the pi once you have it up and running. Once you confirm thats working properly. You can then tie in the cloud controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have come a relatively long way from what I knew when asking this question. For other new programmers trying to figure out how to bring their project/idea to reality here is what I did to deploy my local flask web server on the pi to "the cloud":

I used a company named linode to host my web server on, but there are many other cloud platforms you could choose from like digital ocean and heroku. All I did was purchase their entry level plan, connect via ssh to the new server, copy over the files containing my web server, and add security provisions. Then you can use ssh to connect to your server and use the terminal to do what you need. This was the processes that I followed to deploy to the cloud. There are an abundance of options and ways to do this, but I found this option relatively flexible and cost effective...giving me the chance to participate in the IoT world.

I know this information is obvious to a lot of experienced programmers, but for the ones just getting started I hope this explanation can provide some clarity on your way forward.

Comment: Hi, so as I understand it you moved your management server (Flask) from your local network to the cloud. That would mean that the communication between the Pi and the management server is now exposed to new threats (e.g. an adversary outside your local network might try and take control of your Pi). How is the communication between your Flask server to your Pi secured?

Comment: I am communicating with the pi using mqtt communication on port 1883. I need to switch to a secure port when i send data messages to and from the pi. I also need to use some form of ssl certificates when communicating with the pi. I am obviously still new and need to figure out how integrate security solutions to this project.